# Django creating one-to-one records matching user account

Tags: python, django

I am creating a django application that needs a one-to-one relationship between the user and an informational record.

The application is meant to allow users to maintain a single record about their organization.

I've been struggling with understanding how to enter data through a form. I've tried many different approaches, but here is the most recent attempt.

The workflow for a user is:

1. Login and get redirected to the member view.
2. If the organization profile exists, display it. If the organization profile does not exist, redirect to the edit view.
3. In the edit view, if the request contains POST data, add it to the organization profile and save it. If it does not contain POST data, create an instance to allow the user to enter the data.

A blank record is created in the database, and the form generates correctly, but the results of the form are not being saved into the database.

I think what's tripping me up is correctly creating the record and storing the results through the foreign key relationship, but I've tried everything that I can think of.

All help is much appreciated.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Program(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name')
    ...
```

**views.py:**

```
def member(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        current_user = request.user
        record_data, record_exists = Program.objects.get_or_create(user=current_user)

        if record_exists:
            return render(request, 'programs_dbase/member.html', {'record_data': record_data})
        else:
            return render(request, 'programs_dbase/member.html', {'record_exists': record_exists})

    elif request.user.is_authenticated() is False:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')


def edit(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.method == 'POST':
        current_user = request.user
        record_data = Program.objects.get(user=current_user)
        form = ProgramForm(request.POST, instance=record_data)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/member/')

    elif request.user.is_authenticated() and request.method != 'POST':
        current_user = request.user
        record_data = Program.objects.get(user=current_user)
        program_info = ProgramForm(request.POST, instance=record_data)

        return render(request, 'programs_dbase/edit.html', {'program_info': program_info})

    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

***UPDATE 1: Adding html form and forms.py***

**html:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form action="/edit/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <label for="unit_name">Name</label> {{ program_info.unit_name }}<br />
        <!-- snip -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from models import Program


class ProgramForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Program
        fields = '__all__'
```

***UPDATE 2: adding print command in views.py to evaluate form results***

Added "print form" in views.py immediately before "if form.is_valid():" and can see the result in the terminal:

```
<tr>
  <th>
    <label for="id_user">User:</label>
  </th>
  <td>
    <ul class="errorlist">
      <li>This field is required.</li>
    </ul>
    <select id="id_user" name="user">
      <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
      <option value="1">twitch</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Get this after adding "print form.errors":

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>user<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

***UPDATE 3: Specifying the user for the initial form:***

Tried changing this:

```
program_info = ProgramForm(request.POST, instance=record_data, initial={'user': current_user})
```

But the 'user' value for the field is not actually being selected when the form is generated. WTF; strange.

Comment: Please put your form here too.

Comment: @Luca Hi, I wasn't sure which you wanted to see, so I've added both. Thanks!

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Would you please make sure the form is valid in your controller by having a break or print message under `if form.is_valid():` ?

Comment: That's probably it. When form isn't valid, it's still redirecting to /member/.

Comment: @danielcorreia no error, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried rendering the form with just the {{ form }} statement instead of printing each field individually, so you can see default error output?

Comment: @LucasMoeskops Hi - I added the output from your advice. It looks like there is a required (but hidden) field that was being left blank. I'll try to fix that and post the results. I haven't tried to render with {{ form }}, but will try it if I can't solve the blank field problem.

Comment: Found the errors, but not sure how to fix this. The goal is to have the form belong to the user.

Comment: What other fields exist in your Program model? Maybe some initial data is required.

Comment: @danielcorreia There are dozens of fields, but only a few are marked as not null. The only error I'm getting now is listed at the bottom of "Updated 2" in my problem description. I *think* what's tripping me up is making sure that the "user" field (which is a foreign key to the user object model) is filled out when the form is submitted. I've tried specifying initial={"user": current_user} but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does the user fill out the 'user' part themselves or is it hidden?

Comment: @onyeka it'd be hidden.

Comment: Also, you say the new blank Organization Profiles are created? Does this include the user field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not posting the whole form, but going off what I see, the user doesn't explicitly select their username on the form. Therefore, you need to make sure that column is manually filled from the view before saving.

```
def edit(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.method == 'POST':
        current_user = request.user
        record_data = Program.objects.get(user=current_user)
        form = ProgramForm(request.POST, instance=record_data)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = current_user
            instance.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/member/')

    elif request.user.is_authenticated() and request.method != 'POST':
        current_user = request.user
        record_data = Program.objects.get(user=current_user)
        program_info = ProgramForm(request.POST, instance=record_data)

        return render(request, 'programs_dbase/edit.html', {'program_info': program_info})

    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

Of course, another thing you could do is from the models.py, set the field's editable property to False. That's what I do for User OnetoOnes, since the expectation is that I'll never need to change that user field after creation.

Comment: thanks! I have to wait 12 hours to award the bounty, but your example put me in the right direction and now everything is working exactly like I want. :)